# android fragment popBackStack without POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE

Tags: android, stack, fragment

I have a deep, nested, fragment application.
When I use the below code all works.

```
fragmentManager.popBackStack("root", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

However I want to keep the root fragment so I call

```
fragmentManager.popBackStack("root", 0);
```

But it doens't work, the Stack is the same.
I'm sure that "root" is present because when I use the first code all is done in the right way.

Comment: If you always want to keep the root, you can just omit the addToBackStack() call when you originally add the root fragment.  Otherwise I think you probably need to find the back-stack name of the fragment on top of the root.  You can look through the entries  (which are NOT fragment instances!) using backStackEntryCount() and getBackStackEntryAt().

Answer (score 3):

there's a trick to pop everything, just:

```
fm.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

Comment: I want to pop everything before "root" fragment.